# Как сделать, чтобы при пустой таблице выводился текст?

Tags: php, html

Я вывожу данные из бд в таблицу.
Я хочу, чтобы если данных не было, то таблица была не просто пустая, а писалось "Тут пока ничего нет"
Вопрос: как это сделать?

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th class="var">Вариант</td>
        <th>Баллы</th>
        <th>Время</th>
    </tr>
    <?php
        $count = 1;
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) { 
    ?>
        <tr>
            <td class="var">
                <a href="/check/<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" class="menu__item"><?php echo $row['subject']; ?></a>
            </td>
            <td>
                <?php echo $row['score']; ?> / <?php echo $row['count']; ?>
            </td>
            <td>
                <?php echo $row['time_of_submission']; ?>
            </td>               
            <tr>
    <?php
            $count++;
        } 
    ?>
</table>
```

Comment: У вас присвоение строки происходит в `while`. Просто вынесите его и проверьте строки на пустоту перед выводом `$rows = mysqli_fetch_all($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC);` и если `!empty($rows)` выводим таблицу

Answer (score 0):

Способов несколько. Как минимум

1. Сделать отдельный запрос на получение количества записей соответствующих условию (т.е. использовать `SELECT COUNT(1) FROM.....`). И использовать именно этот единственный запрос с единственным значением, от которого отталкиваться (т.е. делать `if`).
2. Можно сделать текущий запрос и предварительно все данные сложить в массив. А далее работать именно с массивом и смотреть, если `count($arr)` равен нулю - то записей нет, в ином случае начинать работать с массивом в цикле.
3. Можно сделать текущий запрос и спросить длину результата (`$field_cnt = mysqli_num_fields($result);`), и разветвиться по if

Comment: Можно сделать текущий запрос и спросить длину результата, и разветвиться по if

Comment: @splash58 добавил и этот вариант, но, почему изначально не стал, т.к. что-то ощущение, что автору проще для понимания будет первые два..... с учётом как он работает с запросом и html))

Answer (score 0):

```
$count=$result->field_count;
if($count>0){
//выводите таблицу
}
else{
//выводите текст
}
```